# Invoking arbitrary javascript in a WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I am loading a webpage in a WebBrowser control in Windows Phone 7.1 using the following code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.webBrowser1.IsScriptEnabled = true;
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://xkcd.com/"));
        this.webBrowser1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(mouseMove);
    }

    void mouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var a = this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript(
            "eval", 
             new[] { "document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('topContainer')); " });
    }
```

It is throwing the following exception: `An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020101.` The code `document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('topContainer'));` works in chrome console, but throws an exception here. Why? Note that the javascript DOES get executed, just throws an exception.

Comment: 80020101 points to an error while evaluating the javaScript. Try putting some text in your `alert()` for a start... Also, why are calling eval?

Comment: I'm using eval because I will need to evaluate a script, not just one function call. This is the only way I am aware of to call arbitrary javascript on an external webpage using the WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make your code work by putting the `InvokeScript` in the Loaded event of the `WebBrowser` instead of `MouseMove`.

I guess the `MouseMove` event was triggered too rapidly, causing synchronization issues with the `WebBrowser` control.

Here is the code that works:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.webBrowser1.IsScriptEnabled = true;
    this.webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://xkcd.com/"));
    this.webBrowser1.LoadCompleted += webBrowser1_LoadCompleted;
}

void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var a = this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript(
        "eval",
            new[] { "document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('topContainer')); " });
}
```